# Warnings during Ubuntu Update 14.10

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

For some days I got the red circle in the notification bar. After not being able to run software-updater, I tried using apt-get update.

This is what I got:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG A040830F7FAC5991 Google, Inc. Linux Package Signing Key <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: I am getting the same thing on two different machines. It looks like Google's apt repo is currently having some problems. I just removed the repo for now. I'll add it back later in the hopes they fix it soon. Without this repository you won't get updates to Chrome or other Google software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to remove/disable that source (http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release) on your APT configuration.

You can do that at graphical interface of Program Update on Configurations > Another Programs tab, unchecking the respective line.

Or you can do that editing the file /etc/apt/sources.list using your preferred editor (gedit, vim, etc). Considering that you are going to need sudo to do that, you can use the following sequence: Alt-F2 > insert "gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list" > enter your password when asked > edit the file to add a "#" character at the line "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release .. "

Comment: Still getting "the package system is broken"

Comment: So the problem should be other, try running "apt-get -f install", that will try to fix Apt, as described [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/458558/what-is-sudo-apt-get-f-install).